# How fix not working ActionResult Update in NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm learning about .NET Core and I'm using code from [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bd8b0b/how-to-implement-insert-update-delete-functionality-in-singl/). But my update sql is not working.

Here is the index view code:

```
        public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.Operation = id;
        ViewBag.Name = db.Chars.ToList();
        Chars Chars = db.Chars.Find(id);
        return View(Chars);
    }
```

As for now it work I see results from sql and here is the updated part:

```
        public ActionResult Update(Chars Chars)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(Chars).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = 0 });
    }
```

Here is `index.cshtml` part:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm()
{
    @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<MVC__test_2.Chars>)ViewBag.Name)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.CharName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.CharID, new { id = item.CharID })
            </div>
        </div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", new { id = item.CharID }) 
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="Update"
       style=@((ViewBag.Operation != null && Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.Operation) > 0)   ? "display:block" : "display:none") />
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a .net core tutorial, the article was written in 2016 and .net core was released in 2016. Probably you should use the official Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Kindly let us know what an error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the tutorial you provided , I made a demo to test and it updated the data well. The following is the working example , you could refer to and make the modification as per your need .

**Model**

```
public class Description
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.Operation = id;
        ViewBag.Name = _context.Description.ToList();
        Description description= _context.Description.Find(id);
        return View(description);
    }

public ActionResult Update(Description description)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Entry(description).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = 0 });
    }
```

**Index.cshtml** , you should hide the id of the modified data in the modification section.

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Description 

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Description >)ViewBag.Name)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-10">
               @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Display, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
               @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id, new { id = item.Id })
           </div>
       </div> 
       @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Index", new { id = item.Id })
   }

   // Create or Update data
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <div class="form-horizontal">
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
       <fieldset>
          <legend> <b>Entry Screen</b></legend>
          <div class="form-group">
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Display, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
             <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Display)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Display)
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <p>
                  <input type="submit" value="Create" name="Create"
                       style=@((ViewBag.Operation != null && Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.Operation) > 0) ? "display:none" : "display:block") />
                  <input type="submit" value="Update" name="Update"
                       style=@((ViewBag.Operation != null && Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.Operation) > 0) ? "display:block" : "display:none") />
              </p>
          </div>
       </fieldset>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: Hey. In     // Create or Update data part Html.LabelFor and Html.HiddenFor is empty. In @Html.EditorFor is ok. But without this id i can't update sql.  Any way all is in index.cshtml

Comment: @Adam , Html.LabelFor should show the name of  the  property that you want to create/update , Html.HiddenFor is used to hide the id of the data that you want to update in order to  find and update data based on id from the view.

Comment: Excuse me. I made a mistake and did not realize it. Your code is working and it's fine. My mistake was in ActionResult. It was an "update", and it should be an "index". But it works now. Thanks.